# compiler g++ for C++11

Tags: c++11, g++4.8

I installed g++ 4.8 through macport. I can use it by calling g++-mp-4.8.

I compile with g++ 4.8 this code to see if I got C++11, but the answer is prestandard C++. How is it possible? Note: I want C++11 to can use auto iterators.

```
if( __cplusplus == 201103L ) std::cout << "C++11\n" ;
else if( __cplusplus == 19971L ) std::cout << "C++98\n" ;
else std::cout << "pre-standard C++\n" ;
```

Comment: Did you add the `-std=c++11` flag? Also, you're missing a case for the C++03 standard there. And by "auto iterators" I guess you mean the auto type-deduction, which was available already on GCC 4.7 IIRC.

Comment: The old standard is `199711L`, you are missing one `1`.

@Joachim Pileborg: C++03 did not introduce new value of `__cplusplus`

Answer (score 4):

Compile your program with the -std=c++11 flag.

Comment: Thank you, it was the -std flag missing.